# Append a background image based upon their data-attribute via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm probably missing some basic thing.. oh well, you guys probably know.

To make things a bit more dynamic, I would like to have specific objects have a background-image added by their unique data-attribute. Their data attribute will be the file name, while the path will always be same, printed already in the jQuery.

*I know the problem lies within the image URL path, because the quotes aren't completed before the first '+'.. But how to fix that?*

**Html:**

```
<div class='FPNewsitem' data-imgname="hallo"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.FPNewsitem').each(function() {
        var itemImage = $(this).data("imgname");
        $(this).css("background-image", "url('../images/newsitems/" + itemImage + ".jpg');");
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

update: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sstcrv4z/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out this may help u out

Use .css   $(this).css
 instead of attr

```
$(this).css
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sstcrv4z/8/)

Comment: So.. by using 'debugger' and putting it in a var itself, it's working. That's odd and unusual..

Answer (score 4):

*This answer was given before OP changed the code.

There is no attribute called `background-image`. What you need is `css` which is used to *style* the elements. You don't need `;` when you use my code.

```
$(this).css("background-image", "url('../images/newsitems/" + itemImage + ".jpg')");
```

[Check out more about jQuery.css](http://api.jquery.com/css)

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer  one more thing u need to note in amit's answer is he removed the ; next to the ".jpg') if still this happens i would like to ask r u getting any errors in console?

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer check the console for any errors then.

Comment: Well.. the following error didn't appear before, but the current (and only) error that's given is "Unexpected token '(' (line 4:js)

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Good idea. Have a moment :)
Update: how would I do that, since the image path is local.. ? And the issue lies within the path.

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer u can directly refer the online images i think this will be some kind of typo error lets c

Comment: Well, the error about the ')' has been fixed (strangely), but the rather strange thing is that when I say "background, "red" it does append a red background, but if I append a image url divided by '+' it doesn't show up in the css, nor there is an error in the console.. So the problem lies within the formatting of the image URL. That's for sure..

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer Well then create a fiddle man. one more thing no need to put comma in var itemImage = $(this).data("imgname"), use semicolan instead like var itemImage = $(this).data("imgname");

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer I'm having a look at it

Comment: @SundarRajan I know about the comma/semi-colon. Was from old code, but didn't saw I had put it in the code in the OP. Thanks for reminding. But I can verify that was not the problem.. :)